# mod_rewrite with multiple query strings?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to cleanup some URLs on my blog, so I've decided to look into mod_rewrite. I haven't a clue what I'm doing though, so I was hoping I could get some help :P I have links like `http://kn3rdmeister.com/blog/post.php?y=2012&m=07&d=04&id=4`. Although it works, and people still get the content I want them to have, I don't like them having to look at all the query strings. I want to turn the above link into `http://kn3rdmeister.com/blog/2012/07/04/4.php`.

This is what my .htaccess looks like right now.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^y=([0-9){4})&m=([0-9]{2})&d=([0-9]{2})&id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^/blog/post\.php$ http://kn3rdmeister.com/blog/%1/%2/%3/%4.php? [L]
```

Like I said, I'm absolutely clueless :D

Comment: It is much clearer if you only ask one question at a time. Please split one of them off into a separate post.

Comment: Regarding this question, what effect do these three lines in your .htaccess have on the example URL? Does it change at all?

Comment: Nothing changes. The .htaccess is in my website's root directory. Could it help if I make another .htaccess in the blog directory, and then edit the rule accordingly?

Comment: There is a typo in the pattern. The first ) should be a ]. Is that the post, or your actual .htaccess that has the typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using apache 2.0 or higher, you're going to need to remove the leading slash (the prefix) if these rules are in an .htaccess file, so that your regular expression looks like this:

```
# also note this needs to be a "]"--v
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^y=([0-9]{4})&m=([0-9]{2})&d=([0-9]{2})&id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^blog/post\.php$ http://kn3rdmeister.com/blog/%1/%2/%3/%4.php? [L]
```

This is going to make it so when someone puts `http://kn3rdmeister.com/blog/post.php?y=2012&m=07&d=04&id=4` in their browser's URL address bar, their browser will get redirected to `http://kn3rdmeister.com/blog/2012/07/04/4.php` and the new URL will appear in their address bar.

I assume you've got something setup on your server to handle a request like `blog/2012/07/04/4.php`.

Comment: Thank you @Jon, that worked fine. However, I don't have anything setup to handle the redirection :P where would you suggest starting for that? this perhaps needs its own separate post.

Comment: You could probably use mod_proxy with ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse. Might be overkill, but it should do the rewriting in both directions. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Comment: That looks promising... buuut I'm a n00b at this. I'll start a new question, as to keep things clean :P thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

At first you should define your URLs!!!

Like:

`/blog` shows `front page`

`/blog/1234` shows `post 1234`

`/blog/date/2012` shows `posts by year`

`/blog/date/2012/06` shows `posts by year and month`

`/blog/date/2012/06/01` shows `posts by year and month and day`

and so on...

First option is to rewrite each of your defined URLs to index.php. Your index.php has only to handle the submitted GET parameters.

```
### Do only if rewrite is installed
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

### Start rewrite and set basedir
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

### Rewrite only if no file link or dir exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

### Rewrite frontpage
RewriteRule ^blog$ /index.php?action=showfront [L,QSA]

### Rewrite post
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?action=showpost_by_id&id=$1 [L,QSA]

### Rewrite posts by date
RewriteRule ^blog/date/([0-9]{4})$ /index.php?action=showposts_by_date&year=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/date/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})$ /index.php?action=showposts_by_date&year=$1&month=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/date/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})$ /index.php?action=showposts_by_date&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3 [L,QSA]

### Rewrite posts by tag
RewriteRule ^blog/tag/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?action=showposts_by_tag&tag=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Test in index.php with:
    print_r($_GET);
    print_r($_POST);

The second option is to rewrite all URLs and your index.php needs to handle all possible URLs. So at first it needs something like a router that splits the incoming URL in parts and then send the requested page or an error-page. I would try this at first as the bloody school.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^ index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

</IfModule>
```

Test in index.php with:

```
print_r(explode('/', ltrim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/')));
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
```

The third option is to use a PHP framework. A framework may help you to write your code quite fast. It delivers you many base-classes like a router. (f.e. ZendFramework, Flow3, Kohana, Symfony, CodeIgniter, CakePHP, yii and others). This will make you more advanced.

The fourth and laziest option is to use a ready made software like Wordpress.

Comment: Woah... That's a lot of info to look at :D I'll look into all of that at a later time (a few hours, likely). I think I may need to reconsider how I display and post my content, so that I can expand the range of things I can play with.

Comment: Your "first option" answer turns /blog/date/2012/07/04/4.php into index.php?action=showposts_by_date&year=1234&month=05&day=21 . But the questioner wants the opposite effect.