# Htaccess rewrite with question mark

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this type of link :

http://www.domain.it/index.php?module=Test&func=Prova

I would that when i add /en before /index.php

rewrite with

http://www.domain.it/index.php?module=Test&func=Prova&lang=en

I tried several methods but always rewrite index.php&lang=en
The problem seems to be ?

```
RewriteRule ^(en)/(.*)$ $2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but nothing to do.

Comment: With this answer you can solve your problem:

[Mod Rewrite Multiple Query String][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387722/mod-rewrite-with-multiple-query-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding those lines to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ $2?%{QUERY_STRING}&lang=$1 [L]
```

This will save the language in $1 and the origin in $2 so it can be used from other pages, besides `index.php` and with other languages besides `en`.

Also, to test those things, you can use sites like [this](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) one.